# Is there a way to make Android Studio by default make the text you put in black and the background white (Dark theme)

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, themes

I want to create an app that's dark themed by default, but every time I create a new text view or activity or anything it's light themed by default and I have to manually set the text to white and background dark.

Is there a way to make this by default so I don't have to manually set it?

Answer (score 1):

paste inside of `/res/values/themes.xml`

`<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">` is used for static dark theme

More info: https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark